# Why jQuery .animate({opacity:0}) changes the z-index too

Tags: jquery, z-index, opacity

Basically the title says everything - why  jQuery .animate({opacity:0}) changes the z-index too?

Do you know how to solve it?

EDIT:
link to example: http://jsfiddle.net/4vUc7/

Thanks.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Edited my post with link to fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like it's not jQuery because using a fixed opacity of e.g. `0.7` also causes it to shine through.

Comment: I don't know why that's happening, I did re-organize your jsfiddle though so its not all in the HTML box http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/4vUc7/1/

Comment: Possible explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837057/what-has-bigger-priority-opacity-or-z-index-in-browsers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were missing a semicolon in your `z-index`

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vUc7/4/)

Comment: It did solve my problem but the real question is why I had to use z-index in first place? jquery .animate({opacity:0}) changes the z-index of the element. Btw the missing semicolon is a stupid mistake :|

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [question linked by jen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837057/what-has-bigger-priority-opacity-or-z-index-in-browsers), this is not a jQuery bug but a browser problem. If you monitor the properties of the element whose opacity is being toggled in a debug console you'll notice that only opacity is being touched. jQuery is not touching the `z-index`, but the browser renders elements with opacity that isn't equal to 1 differently.

I've made a few extra changes to your code: http://jsfiddle.net/radu/4vUc7/6/.