# Why does opacity negate pointer events?

Tags: css, opacity

In the following setup, why does the click event (and any other pointer event) not get fired?

If you remove the `opacity: 0.5` line, it will work fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/523ve/

For posterity, in case jsFiddle ever goes down (December 21 *is* approaching):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a>Click</a>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { position: relative; margin: 40px; }
a { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }
p { opacity: 0.5; }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        alert("Alert");
    });
});
```

(Tested in latest stable Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: That is weird! I'd like to know why too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "Since an element with opacity less than 1 is composited from a single offscreen image, content outside of it cannot be layered in
>   z-order between pieces of content inside of it. For the same reason,
>   implementations must create a new stacking context for any element
>   with opacity less than 1. If an element with opacity less than 1 is
>   not positioned, implementations must paint the layer it creates,
>   within its parent stacking context, at the same stacking order that
>   would be used if it were a positioned element with `z-index: 0` and
>   `opacity: 1`..."

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency

---

**EDIT**:

Also, your particular example has the `<p>` element overlapping the `<a>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/523ve/4/

So you could fix this by either moving the `<a>` so that it does not interfere, or by using `z-index` to re-adjust the stacking order.  The latter option may have cross-browser issues but I have not tested.  I recommend re-factoring your HTML so that these two elements do not overlap with each other.

---

**EDIT 2**:

Here is a related SO question, however the accepted answer is incorrect.

[What has bigger priority: opacity or z-index in browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837057/what-has-bigger-priority-opacity-or-z-index-in-browsers)

Comment: +1 i would rather want to see this without italic paragraph its ... braking my eyes

Comment: @NullPointer, noted & fixed.  Although one could read the same paragraph at the source link.

Comment: Great answer, explanation and reference. I fixed it by setting the `z-index` to 1.

Answer (score 3):

you might understand by this line

The opacity CSS property specifies the transparency of an element, that is, the degree to which the **background behind the element is overlaid**.

Using this property with a value different than 1 places the element in a new stacking context.

[source :MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/opacity)

and here `p` is overlapping `a` so either set the width of `p` to not overlap `a` or set `a` higher `z-index`

Answer (score -1):

The `a` element comes before `p`, and note that `p` is 100% wide. This means that `p` is effectively ABOVE `a`.

You can either change `a` element's z-index to something above 0 (http://jsfiddle.net/523ve/5/) or swap `p` and `a` in your HTML so that `a` comes after `p` (http://jsfiddle.net/523ve/3/).

I hope what I've written makes any sense ;).

Comment: -1, this accounts for why the paragraph ought to block the anchor, but does not explain why opacity affects this behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I was writing it up.

Comment: I see. The question was: "*In the following setup*, why does the click event (and any other pointer event) not get fired?". As far as I understand it, I have answered the question in full.

Comment: I've removed my downvote, since this isn't *wrong*, but it is incomplete, as it fails to answer the question of why opacity:1 does not block but opacity less than 1 does.

Comment: Oh, cool. The OP used the `z-index` solution that I first suggested. Keep the downvotes coming. [sigh]

Comment: If you re-read the question, you'll note that the OP was not asking for a fix. He was asking _why_ removing `opacity` was making all the difference.

Comment: I don't agree that this was grounds for a downvote, the poster has explained that the P was above A and a simple z-index will fix it. Some poeple..