# Possible Opacity Z-Index Bug

Tags: css, opacity

I just ran into a really wierd issue when setting opacity on a web page. The element with opacity obscures other elements on the page.This happens in Safari, Chrome and Firefox. Opacity is ignored in IE7 & 8. Not tested on IE9.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V4MrH/)

```
<style>
   #content { opacity: .92; background: #dfd; height: 300px;}
   #sidebar { width: 200px; float: right; background: #fdd; height: 200px; }
</style>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Removing opacity restores the expected behavior. Another possible fix is to use rgba background values instead of opacity.

Has anyone else encountered this? If so, how did you fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837057/what-has-bigger-priority-opacity-or-z-index-in-browsers

Comment: `#content` has a higher z-index than `#sidebar`. Since you aren't using `overflow:hidden;`, `#content` will overlap the floated `#sidebar`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V4MrH/1/

Comment: Thanks for your response @Shmiddty, just not sure I want to force overflow: hidden. I updated my website to use an rgba background.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle with the rgba solution http://jsfiddle.net/V4MrH/28/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is already known.
https://www.google.com/#q=opacity%20change%20z-index

You should use rgba background, which is also a widely supported property.

Comment: I just made this the accepted answer, since it's what actually solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

The opacity you're setting on `#content` is creating a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context), and stacking contexts affect z-indexes. Since you didn't specify z-indexes manually, they're being auto assigned, and `#content` has a higher value than `#sidebar` because it comes later in the markup.

A simple CSS solution: just add `position: relative; z-index: 2` to `#sidebar` (to establish yet another stacking context). On your real code, you may need to add a z-index to `#content` too, if you have more elements under `#wrapper`:

```css
#sidebar { position: relative; z-index: 2; /* etc */ }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V4MrH/3/

Comment: So this is by design, but rather counter-intuitive, that adding opacity to an object would affect the layout of a web page.

Comment: Yes, it's totally counter-intuitive. But once you find out how it works, it actually makes sense.

Comment: I tried using position: relative to fix the problem, but with no luck. http://jsfiddle.net/WzvLU/1/ This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Luke I'm not sure what you're trying to do and what the problem is. I believe you should post your own question!