# Using opacity to change the stacking order

Tags: html, css

> can anyone explain why does opacity have any affect on stacking of
>   html element ?

Relevant part of the CSS Code:

```
    div:first-child{
        opacity: 0.99;
    }
    .red{
        background: red;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .green{
        background: green;
        margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
    }
    .blue{
        background: blue;
        margin: 40px 0 0 40px;
    }
```

Plain HTML:

```
<div>
  <span class="red"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="green"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="blue"></span>
</div>
```

I am learning about z-index, it seemed pretty simple until i encountered this exception where it seems to have no affect on the stacking order after addition of opacity, can anyone explain the significance of opacity in this particular context?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837057/what-has-bigger-priority-opacity-or-z-index-in-browsers

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

## UPGRADE

### See Snippet 2

> - In order for `z-index` to be of any use, the element has to to have one of the following:
>
>   - `position:absolute`
>   - `position:relative`
>   - `position:fixed`

---

> - `opacity` works on a scale of 0 to 1, so having a .99 is useless.

---

> - `<span>`s `inline` elements and don't start with any discernable width or height, so in order to actually see any background, you need to give them some dimensions (i.e. height and width) or content (i.e. text inside of them). It also helps if you assign `display:inline-block` because dealing with `display:inline` isn't intuitive.

In Snippet 1 I've added the what was previously mentioned in your code.

In Snippet 2 I have made an interactive demo showing `z-index` and `opacity` stacking relationship.

**SNIPPET 1**

```css
div:first-child {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.red {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
.green {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
.blue {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  margin: 40px 0 0 40px;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="red"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="green"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="blue"></span>
</div>
```

**SNIPPET 2**

```js
document.getElementById('rng1').oninput = function() {
  var rad = document.querySelectorAll('.rad:checked')[0];
  var out = rad.nextElementSibling.id;
  document.getElementById(rad.value).style.opacity = this.value;
  document.getElementById(out).value = this.value;
}
```

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px dashed grey;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-align: right;
}
fieldset {
  width: 450px;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
#A {
  background: tomato;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: left;
}
#B {
  background: cyan;
  z-index: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#C {
  background: yellow;
  z-index: -10;
  text-align: right;
}
output {
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section id='parent'>
  <div id='A'>A</div>
  <div id='B'>B</div>
  <div id='C'>C</div>
  Parent
</section>

<form id='ui'>
  <fieldset>
    <label>
      <input id='radA' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio' value='A' checked>A:
      <output id='oA'></output>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input id='radB' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio' value='B'>B:
      <output id='oB'></output>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input id='radC' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio' value='C'>C:
      <output id='oC'></output>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input id='radD' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio' value='parent'>Parent:
      <output id='oD'></output>
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>Opacity
      <input id='rng1' type='range' min='0' max='1' step='.1' value='1'>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```