# CSS Opacity only works with 0 or 1

Tags: css, opacity, fixed

I have a strange behaviour when transitioning the opacity of a modal background. Transition starts from 0 and ends with 1. I see that the transition is working in the area where no other HTML element is. It fades perfectly from 0 to 1.

But I use a fixed header and footer. While transitioning from 0 to 0.9999.. the header / footer are always fully visible over the modal. When opacity reaches the value 1, it's finally overlapping the header and footer.

I thought of the z-index at first, but that doesn't make sense because when the opacity reaches 1 it's overlapping the header and footer.

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #002d42;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    background-color: red; /** #004666 **/
}
```

I expect that the modal background also fades over the fixed header and footer elemented and not only is overlapping when the opacity reached the value 1.

Comment: Difficult to diagnose without a working snippet or a link to the page. Can you provide 1?

Comment: http://styledesign.de/example/

Modal opens with click on the footer links.

Comment: Careful differentiating between modal and modal wrapper.  The animation certainly works on the wrapper but the modal ( which covers the entire screen) may not.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837057/what-has-bigger-priority-opacity-or-z-index-in-browsers - it's all to do with the stacking context - changing the opacity below 1 will change the stacking context and bring z-indexes into play so it is to do with the z-index too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give a fixed position to your modal container too

```
#modal {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

If not, its position is static by default and doesn't care about z-indexes untill its child `<div class="modal">` is fully loaded.

Position `relative` or `absolute` would also work but not default `static`.

Comment: As I said it's not because of the z-index. The modal overlaps everything when the opacity finally reaches 1. I however tried your approach with positon: fixed and now it's not overlapping anymore, even when the opacity of 1 has been reached.