# JS loop to add event listeners not working during one condition for second element

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, nodelist

I am working on a piece of code to toggle the visibility of some UL items by clicking corresponding buttons by toggling a class on the UL that changes opacity/height to 0 (so that I can also apply transitions). The second element doesn't work when the first is toggled to be invisible. The onclick event does not register.

The code works when the button and h3 are not styled to appear on the same line, and breaks when I try to use flex, float, or inline to position the two elements side by side. Is there a method that I can use to position them as such and still retain full functionality?

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
const lists = document.getElementsByClassName("list");

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    toggle(i);
  })
};

function toggle(i) {
  if (lists[i].classList.contains("hide")) {
    lists[i].classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
    lists[i].classList.add("hide");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="side">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Protein</h3>
      <button class="toggle"></button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="list">
        <li class="fi">Beef</li>
        <li class="fi">Fish</li>
        <li class="fi">Lamb</li>
        <li class="fi">Pork</li>
        <li class="fi">Poultry</li>
        <li class="fi">Shellfish</li>
        <li class="fi">Vegetarian</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="side">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Cuisine</h3>
      <button class="toggle"></button>
    </div>
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="fi">African</li>
      <li class="fi">American</li>
      <li class="fi">Asian</li>
      <li class="fi">British</li>
      <li class="fi">Cajun Creole</li>
      <li class="fi">Carribean</li>
      <li class="fi">Eastern European</li>
      <li class="fi">Show More</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
   .header{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
   }
   
   .hide {
   height: 0;
   opacity: 0;
   margin: 0;
   }
</style>
```

[gif of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs7vU.gif)

Comment: Code looks reasonable. Can you edit the HTML into the question in a live Stack Snippet so we can see the problem too?

Comment: Just added, thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Interesting... It is working like I want it to as a snippet. I'll try rebuilding without extra CSS, or perhaps looking at if there's a difference in the environment. Thank you for the Stack Overflow tips!

Comment: The snippet works just fine.

Comment: is there a reason you have to use opacity for hiding?  it is interfering with and covering the second list.

Comment: In the gif u added, it seems like the button is not even clicking, not that hiding/showing the list is not working alone, the button is not clicking at all

Answer (score 0):

I've added pointer-events: none so it doesn't intercept mouse events and it works, but you should probably find another way to deal with it.  I don't know what you're doing for animations, code, nor the rest of the styling, so this might be the best solution depending on what you're doing.
I've added a "Show Problem" button to show what's happening.  The list is (repainted in a new stacking context triggered by opacity) and covering the second list.

*Another solution is to set the position style.  So adding `position: relative` to the `.hide { position: relative }` will also work*

Scroll to bottom to read a detailed description of the cause (opacity style).

```js
// show problem
test.onclick=()=>{
  if (lists[0].classList.contains("hide1")) {
    lists[0].classList.remove("hide1");
  } else {
    lists[0].classList.add("hide1");
  }
}



const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
const lists = document.getElementsByClassName("list");

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    toggle(i);
  })
};

function toggle(i) {
  if (lists[i].classList.contains("hide")) {
    lists[i].classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
    lists[i].classList.add("hide");
  }
}
```

```css
.header { display:flex; flex-direction:row }

   .header{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
   }
   
   .hide {
   height: 0;
   opacity: 0;
   margin: 0;
   pointer-events: none /* don't intercept mouse events */
   }

/* show problem */
.hide1 {
height: 0;
margin: 0;
opacity: 0.5;
border: 1px solid red;
}

.hide1 * {
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<button id="test">Show Problem</button>

<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="side">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Protein</h3>
      <button class="toggle"></button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="list">
        <li class="fi">Beef</li>
        <li class="fi">Fish</li>
        <li class="fi">Lamb</li>
        <li class="fi">Pork</li>
        <li class="fi">Poultry</li>
        <li class="fi">Shellfish</li>
        <li class="fi">Vegetarian</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="side">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Cuisine</h3>
      <button class="toggle"></button>
    </div>
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="fi">African</li>
      <li class="fi">American</li>
      <li class="fi">Asian</li>
      <li class="fi">British</li>
      <li class="fi">Cajun Creole</li>
      <li class="fi">Carribean</li>
      <li class="fi">Eastern European</li>
      <li class="fi">Show More</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
   .header{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
   }
   
   .hide {
   height: 0;
   opacity: 0;
   margin: 0;
   pointer-events: none
   }
</style>
```

The problem is related to the z-index stacking context being triggered by the opacity style due to re-render: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context
You can prove this by setting `opacity: 0.9` on the second list's header, so that the second list's header renders in the same context layer, and see that you will then be able to click the button.
This SO answer summarizes it well:
[What has bigger priority: opacity or z-index in browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837057/what-has-bigger-priority-opacity-or-z-index-in-browsers)
**If an element with opacity less than 1 is not positioned, implementations must paint the layer it creates, within its parent stacking context, at the same stacking order that would be used if it were a positioned element with ‘z-index: 0’ and ‘opacity: 1’**

Answer (score 0):

As the response for user120242 says you are overlaying the below `side class div` you can resolve it by adding your `<div class="side">` element a `overflow: hidden;` style to avoid overflowing the below div, so try this:

If you want to place elements next to each other you need working with flexbox as @user120242 said.

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
const lists = document.getElementsByClassName("list");

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    toggle(i);
  })
};

function toggle(i) {
  if (lists[i].classList.contains("hide")) {
    lists[i].classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
    lists[i].classList.add("hide");
  }
}
```

```css
.side {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="side">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Protein</h3>
      <button class="toggle"></button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="list">
        <li class="fi">Beef</li>
        <li class="fi">Fish</li>
        <li class="fi">Lamb</li>
        <li class="fi">Pork</li>
        <li class="fi">Poultry</li>
        <li class="fi">Shellfish</li>
        <li class="fi">Vegetarian</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="side">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Cuisine</h3>
      <button class="toggle"></button>
    </div>
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="fi">African</li>
      <li class="fi">American</li>
      <li class="fi">Asian</li>
      <li class="fi">British</li>
      <li class="fi">Cajun Creole</li>
      <li class="fi">Carribean</li>
      <li class="fi">Eastern European</li>
      <li class="fi">Show More</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
   .header{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
   }
   
   .hide {
   height: 0;
   opacity: 0;
   margin: 0;
   }
</style>
```