# Why does opacity make an element appear above another, if an element without is appears below?

Tags: html, css, absolute

I have an absolutely positioned flyout table, that is hidden (`display:none;`) by default,
and appears (`display:block;`) on hovering over its heading.
It appears above everything else on the page, which is what I want.

The exception are elements with an `opacity` value below 1.
They appear above the hover table.

Why is that, and how could I avoid it?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/watchduck/xLm8zrgv/6/)
[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is really strange... at first I thought it might have been JSFiddle acting up, but it behaves the same with a html file. I was able to fix it with a `z-index: 1` on the `table.hidden`. But I still don't know why that is happening. CSS is weird XD.

Comment: I also found this confusing. My current interpretation is, that the above/below relationship between table and spans is undefined, because they all have `z-index: auto;`. It kind of makes sense: If we leave something undefined, we have to expect something random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily avoid it by adding `z-index: 1;` to `table.hidden`

Comment: i believe this is a hack based on `opacity`

Comment: css has weird stuff

Comment: I actually don't know why it happens. I would be interesting to know !

Answer (score 1):

This is working "as it should", but to get your desired result, use `z-index: 1` on your `position: absolute` element.

I did some more digging into this because I was curious as to why it was happening. There are two important things:

1. elements with `position: absolute` and a `z-index: auto` stay in the same [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).
2. [an element with an opacity less than 1 creates a new stacking context](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#transparency).

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11742116/20913924) helpful as it goes into more depth about why this happens.